# ¿Como evitar que desde teclado se use un a4j:commandButton en jsf?

Tags: jsf

Tengo en la cabecera de una web un a4j:commandButton el cual responde a algunos eventos provocados desde el teclado del equipo, cuando pulso el enter en el teclado se lanza el action de dicho commandButton, y cuando pulso el boton de delete en el teclado viaja a la pantalla anterior donde estuviera. Si quito el botón no pasa nada de esto.

¿Como podría controlarlo?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto no tiene que ver con JSF, si no con simple HTML. `<a4j:commandButton ...>` se renderiza en un `<button type="submit" ...>`. Por defecto, los botones tipo submit tienen *shortcuts*; en la mayoría de navegadores es igual:

- Enter: dispara el evento submit
- Delete: vuelve a la página anterior

Este problema puedes resolverlo mediante JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 8 && !$(e.target).is("input, textarea")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Para evitar el submit del form cuando se presione un Enter, se debe escuchar por evento keyup en el form y detectar si se ha presionado Enter.

```
$('#tuform').on('keyup', function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode === 13) { // Se detecta Enter
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

**PD:** RichFaces ha sido declarado descontinuado por RedHat. Se recomienda usar JSF plano u otra librería de extensión.

Comment: Entiendo que el keycode del backspace es el 8 y cumpla la condición del if y haga el preventDefault. ¿Pero como es posible que esto funcione para el Enter?. Simplemente es por entenderlo bien, porque funcionar, funciona.

Comment: He actualizado el post para añadir lo que dijiste.